# Could not initilize the SASL library

Tags: svn

Following the tutorial [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/setting-up-subversion-on-windows/), I installed Subversion 1.5.6 (Setup-Subversion-1.5.6.msi [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=91)) on Windows Server 2003 SP2. I was able to create a repository (C:\SVN\Repository) using the command line, no problem. And I can configure it as a service, but when I try to start the service, it won't start. I figured I would try to run svnserve manually without the --service argument, but it errors. I am trying:

svnserve -r c:\svn\repository

...and the error I get is:

svn: Could not initialize the SASL library
svn: generic failure

Other Information that might be pertinent:
I edited the svnserve.conf file by uncommenting the anon-access and auth-access lines:

anon-access = none
auth-access = write

I also uncommented the password-db line:

password-db = passwd

I am logged into the box using remote desktop, and I am logged in as an administrator on the server. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the active directory service running okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The SASL / svnserve configuration is not always an easy step, and is [described in details here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sasl). Here is a summary:

- Don't forget to check the following registry key which must point to your configuration file:

  `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Carnegie Mellon\Project Cyrus\SASL Library]`
  `"ConfFile"="c:\\svn\\etc\\conf"`
- The directory **C:\svn\etc\conf** should contain the `svn.conf` file (or `subversion.conf` should work too), that contains for example:

  `pwcheck_method: auxprop`
  `auxprop_plugin: sasldb`
  `sasldb_path: c:\svn\etc\conf\saslpasswd`
  `mech_list: ANONYMOUS DIGEST-MD5`
- Finally, the `saslpasswd` password file will have to be created for the same domain as declared in your repository, corresponding to the `<domain>` below. Check the `saslpasswd2.exe` command usage for that part.
- In each repository, in the **conf** subdirectory, the `svnserve.conf` file needs the following lines (replace `<domain>`):

  `[general]`
  `authz-db = //./C:/svn/etc/conf/authz`
  `realm = <domain>`
  `[sasl]`
  `use-sasl = true`

2) I had some problems with SASL in the past around version 1.5, with executables from tigris compiled against Apache. It was solved by installing the Collabnet version instead.

See this link: http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/ and for older versions: http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/svn1.5.html but unless you have a very good reason not to, I would install the latest version. The installer will let you choose whether you want to have an Apache or svnserve server.

Comment: I ended up installing the Collabnet version - couldn't see a reason not to. It took care of everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you referenced was for a much older version of Subversion, and may be missing steps.  Nowadays, the fastest way to set up a Subversion server on Windows is to use [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/), whose Standard version is [free (as in beer)](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/eula/) to use.